# Kubernetes Deployment URL Gets 404 Not Found Errors Randomly

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, gunicorn

I have a flask application hosted on Kubernetes with a simple /healthcheck route. I'm trying to ping this route multiple times in the console. Half the time it works, half the time I get a 404 not found error.

What could be causing this? The error shows up consistently but doesn't seem to show up in a pattern. For example, sometimes the first request I send in a while will have the error appear and then trying to hit the endpoint again after like 2-3 tries makes it successful.

This flask server is ran behind gunicorn. The application as a whole is being deployed on Kubernetes where I define a deployment, ingress, and service.

Comment: Does the application have enough resources for what it requires?
I've seen similar issues with applications that are close to OOM crash, which could indicate that you need to up the resources.memory/cpu on the deployment.

Comment: @Jite My resources consists of my requests having 0.5 Gb of memory and 0.5 cpu while my limits have 2 Gb of memory and 1 cpu. I tried upping the memory and cpu for the requests but still having the same problem. I doubt its the resources since I am only trying to hit a health check endpoint.

Comment: @Jite I should also no pods seem to be crashing/restarting either.

Comment: what is the version of your kubernetes?

Comment: @Bazhikov Running this on Amazon EKS. The Kubernetes server version is 1.20+ running on linux/amd64.

Comment: Did you fix it ? or came to know reason for same ? @JohnMunar I am facing same issue